# Converting If/Else into Ternary React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a project in React and Typescript and am creating a Like button and created an if/else statement as so:

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [iconFill, setFill] = useState('gray');

  const favoriteCount = () => {
    if(iconFill == 'red') {
      setCount(count - 1 );
      setFill('gray');
    } 
    else {
      setCount(count + 1);
      setFill('red');
    }
  }
```

The code works as expected but I am wondering if there is a more concise way to write it, I tried using a ternary statement:

```
iconFill == 'red' ? setCount(count - 1 ) && setFill('gray') : setCount(count + 1) && setFill('red');
```

I am unsure of why this doesn't produce the same result and am also getting the following Typescript error:
`An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness`

Comment: Why would this `... ? ... : ...` be any better? Write code that you can understand by only looking at it. Anything else is the job of a specialized tool.

Comment: Typescript says that ```void``` type cannot be casted to ```boolean```. State modifiers returns ```void``` type.

Comment: favoriteCount() is a void function. You should use ternary operator incase you need something in return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your original existing code is fine - using the conditional operator not only makes it a lot harder to read, but it also just *isn't appropriate* because the conditional operator is meant to be used when you want to conditionally produce an *expression* (but the resulting expression here isn't being used). `if/else` is more appropriate.

But there is an alternative that can make your code more concise. Because it looks like `iconFill` toggles between gray and red, how about making that state a *boolean* instead of a string? Then you can just invert the boolean:

```
const [fillGray, setFillGray] = useState(true);
const favoriteCount = () => {
    setCount(count + (fillGray ? 1 : -1));
    setFillGray(!fillGray);
}
```

The conditional operator is used above, but it's in a more appropriate context because the result is used *as an expression* (that is, to evaluate to `1` or `-1`) rather than as an inappropriate replacement for if/else.

Comment: thanks for explanation and the suggestion for the `boolean`, it makes sense and make the code more concise :)

Answer (score 1):

Should you change your code? No, moving to ternary here is not an improvement, so I wouldn't.

Why doesn't your proposed code work? In your proposed code `setCount(count - 1 ) && setFill('gray')`, the `setFill` command will only execute if `setCount` returns [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). In all likelihood, your setter methods return undefined, so the code after `&&` will never execute. There is no point in evaluating `B` in `A && B` if A is false. The evaluation is [short-circuited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Also, minor comment, [prefer](https://bytearcher.com/articles/equality-comparison-operator-javascript/) `===` over `==` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be:

```
    setCount(iconFill === "red" ? count - 1 : count + 1);
    setFill(iconFill === "red" ? "gray" : "red");
```

Here the limitation is checking for condition twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responses everyone, makes sense to me now why ternary would not be appropriate for this scenario, keeping my original!